# Select on all_tab_columns returns ambiguous result when rownum is added in where clause

Tags: select, oracle11g

This is some what a very strange issue I am facing. I have a template table (DATA_TEMPLATE_TABLE) which stores data uploaded from XML. Table DATA_TEMPLATE_TABLE have around 52 columns. When I execute below query it returns first 6 columns:

```
   select TABLE_NAME,column_name from all_tab_columns
   where 1=1 
   and 
   table_name='DATA_TEMPLATE_TABLE'
   AND column_name <>'ID'
   AND column_name <>'QUERY_REF'
   and rownum <=6
   order by column_id;
```

But when I execute it again it gives me last 6 columns. Structure of the table mentioned is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE DATA_TEMPLATE_TABLE
(
  ID         NUMBER                             NOT NULL,
  COL_V1     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V2     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V3     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V4     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V5     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V6     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V7     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V8     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V9     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V10    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V11    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V12    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V13    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V14    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V15    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V16    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V17    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V18    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V19    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V20    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V21    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V22    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V23    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V24    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V25    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V26    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V27    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V28    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V29    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V30    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V31    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V32    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V33    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V34    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V35    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V36    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V37    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V38    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V39    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V40    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V41    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V42    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V43    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V44    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V45    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V46    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V47    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V48    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V49    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  COL_V50    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  QUERY_REF  VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
);
```

What is the problem here, please help as I am unable to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first order by either ascending or descending if you want the same set of columns everything you execute the query

```
 select * from 
 (select TABLE_NAME,column_name from all_tab_columns
 where 1=1 
 and 
 table_name='DATA_TEMPLATE_TABLE'
 AND column_name <>'ID'
 AND column_name <>'QUERY_REF'
 order by column_id)
 where rownum<=6;
```

From an Oracle Magazine Article..

ROWNUM is a pseudocolumn (not a real column) that is available in a query. ROWNUM will be assigned the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, ... N , where N is the number of rows in the set ROWNUM is used with. A ROWNUM value is not assigned permanently to a row (this is a common misconception). A row in a table does not have a number; you cannot ask for row 5 from a table—there is no such thing.

Also confusing to many people is when a ROWNUM value is actually assigned. A ROWNUM value is assigned to a row after it passes the predicate phase of the query but before the query **does any sorting or aggregation**. Also, a ROWNUM value is incremented only after it is assigned, which is why the following query

Comment: Thank you. I have been trying so hard that I missed such a simple solution :) And thank you for your advice.